# URL Regex pattern not accepting multiple parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex to identify URLS with PHP:

```
(?i)\b(?!.*?\<<) 
(?!.*?\.onion) //negative lookaheads for << and .onion
((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|ftp:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)
 (?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?
 (?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*?\)
 |
 [^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’])
)
```

Which works well until it tries to match a URL like these:

```
http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)_(again)
http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1
```

Only the string up to the first ) will match. I have tried making the pattern ungreedy, but that causes catastrophic backtracking when matching this URL:

```
http://google.com/(JavaScript_Add-on)
```

And it is important that all three examples here are fully matched. Here is [A regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/cI5eT2/5) which outlines this problem a little better.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered making your regex readable `~x` first?

Comment: What is your pattern supposed to find? I suspect your pattern is too complicated for nothing.

Comment: What @mario said, why would you write a regex like that with no whitespace or comments? Do you also write your PHP functions all in one line?

Comment: Sorry, I have tidied it up. I did not create this pattern myself, and will admit it is  a little beyond me. The pattern is meant to find any URLs within text.

Comment: "I did not create this pattern myself": all your problems come from that. It is near from impossible to describe the complete syntax of an url with a regex. So the way is to define what kind of urls you need to find (what schemes, and without schemes hostnames with `www` for example) and to build a very simple and naive pattern. Once you have done this, you can always check the syntax with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.

Comment: It functions pretty much perfectly right now, except for the problem I outlined above. I have updated a list https://regex101.com/r/cI5eT2/6 of URLs that it should match and as you can see it only fails when one extends beyond a close parenthesis character. Would you say that trying to identify why a ) is signalling the end of a match is a very difficult problem?